# How to easily clean repeat rows in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am working with the spotifyR package, and pulling artist information for Taylor Swift. I am trying to compare all of her albums, but some albums are listed multiple times in the dataframe.
I have tried the `distinct()` function, but that does not remove all the repeats for some reason. I have also tried going into the data frame and finding the repeat rows that I can delete with `ts <- ts[-c(31:60), ]`. However, when I try to delete the next set of repeat rows, it is offset by a certain number of rows. For example: `ts <- ts[-c(108:124), ]` does not delete rows 108 - 124. It deletes 125 - 141.
How can I easily delete the repeat rows (with a for loop maybe? not sure how to approach) or make sure that when I am manually deleting rows, it does not get offset like it currently is?

Comment: When you do the first assignment `ts <- ts[-...`, the object `ts` would have only a subset of rows i.e

Comment: Have you tried `unique()` or `distinct_all()`? And could you share a example of your data

Comment: @TomHoel both still did not catch the repeats :/. Is there an easy way to share the data besides typing in a table (I am new to StackOverflow, apologies)? It comes directly from the Spotify API, so has artist name, song name, liveliness, danceability, etc. and album name which is what I am trying to filter by.

Comment: @akrun I'm not entirely sure what your comment means. Is there no way for me to remove them, or should I just be removing everything at once? Could you please give me some more info.

Comment: @shrey_shankar what i meant is that `v1 <- 1:10; v1 <- v1[-(2:5)]` now `v1` doesn't have the 10 observations, and thus your second index (based on your original object) is not valid)

Comment: Also, why can't you delete all at once i.e. `ts1 <- ts[-c(31:60, 108:124,...),]` from your original ts object.  It may be also better to rename the subset object i.t. `ts1` or so

Comment: @akrun Oh ok so if I do it all in one shot the indexes won't be incorrect. Gotcha, thank you so much!

Comment: yes, because your indexes are based on original object and not from the reduced object